# Click handler not working, possible unintended reference comparison

Tags: windows-phone-7.1

this doesnt work ,i have an item "Area" in my listBox1,but code is not producing MessageBox in wp7 runtime,

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if( listBox1.SelectedItem=="Area")

        {
            MessageBox.Show("hi");
        }





    }
```

Comment: I am getting no error during compilation but a green line come under listBox1.SelectedItem=="Area" saying "possible unintended reference comparison;to get a value comparison,cast the left hand side to type string"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
listBox1.SelectedItem as string == "Area"
```

You are missing the cast.

Comment: Make sure you understand what the warning message is trying to tell you.